# scrapy how to yield to existing object to mongodb

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to save my data, edit it, and then save it again as the same object(its a dict?).

I save my data with yield {'Id': id, 'Name': name, 'Age': age} to mongodb.

after that i read the data with the following code:

```
import scrapy
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

class example(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['https://example.com']

def __init__(self):
    self.db = MongoClient() 
    self.datab = self.db.database_name.collection_name.find({}) 


def parse(self, response):
    for data in self.datab:
        name = data['Name']
        print(name)
```

the code above will print all the names in data base.
but if for example i want to edit the names like this:

```
    for data in self.datab:
        name = data['Name']
        if name == 'dani':
           name = 'daniel'
           yield{'Name':name}
```

i want it to yield it to the same object it was before.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

EDIT:
pipelines.py:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
from scrapy.conf import settings

class MongoDBPipeline(object):
def __init__(self):
    connection = MongoClient(settings['MONGODB_SERVER'], settings['MONGODB_PORT'])
    db = connection[settings['MONGODB_DB']]
    self.collection = db[settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION']]

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.collection.insert(dict(item))
    return item
```

settings.py:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'quotes_spider.pipelines.MongoDBPipeline': 300,
}
MONGODB_SERVER = 'localhost'
MONGODB_PORT = 27017
MONGODB_DB = 'database_name'
MONGODB_COLLECTION = 'collection_name'
```

Comment: Are you using a pipeline to save this? If so post pipeline code also

Comment: @Tarun Lalwani added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

```
self.collection.insert(dict(item))
```

to

```
if "_id" in item:
   _id = item.pop("_id")
   self.collection.update_one({"_id":_id}, {"$set": item})
else:
   self.collection.insert(dict(item))
```

And this to

```
for data in self.datab:
    name = data['Name']
    if name == 'dani':
       name = 'daniel'
       yield {'_id': data['_id'], 'Name': name}
```

So basically when you want to update you will yield the `_id` and updated fields. When you want to insert you will yield without an `_id`